# Wordpress admin page: wpdb->query() doesn't keep redirect

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a plugin that keeps HTML snippets in _transients. Now, I want to be able to let the users delete all the related transients by clicking on a button. I've managed to create a button, send proper request to options.php page, get the request, and execute query, but the problem is that I'm left at /options.php and I want to redirect to my plugin page. Here are relevant parts of the code:

```
function fbClearTransients(){
    global $wpdb, $_wp_using_ext_object_cache;

    if(!empty($_POST["fb-clear-transient"]) && intval($_POST["fb-clear-transient"]) == 1) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE '%_transient_fb_%'";
        $clean = $wpdb -> query( $sql );
    }
}

function fbClearCache() {
    $clear = fbClearTransients();
}

add_action('admin-init', 'fbClearCache');

[...]

<form action="options.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="fb-clear-transient" value='1'>
        <?php submit_button( __('Clear cache'), 'secondary', 'fb_clear_trans_button', false ); ?>
</form>
```

So, to sum up: query works, everything works, except that I'm not redirected back to my plugin page, as with initial Save button - the one that saves the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I've modified original query that would've take me to the admin.php?page=myplugin, I needed to somehow tell the system I want to end up there, so adding simply:

```
header('Location: admin.php?page=my-plugin');
```

fixed it for me.